# Clicking text doesn't show alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I had a similar question to this before, however, the code I gave was under different circumstances.

Here's what I have now: [**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hHbku**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hHbku)

If you click on the image and then click on the text `"CLICKING THIS SHOULD SHOW THE ALERT"`, it should show the alert that I've told it to show in the JS code, however it's not. Why is this?

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <a href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" title="CLICKING THIS SHOULD SHOW THE ALERT."><img class="example-image" src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/img/demopage/thumb-3.jpg" width="150" height="150"/></a>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=udGNfeN8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".lb-caption" function() {
  alert("CLICKED.");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightbox script binds click handlers to elements of the lightbox. These handlers stop propagation of the event, so it never reaches the `document` and your handler isn't called.

Comment: What are the general fixes for this?

Comment: One option would be to add a click handler directly to the element after the lightbox opens.

Comment: Okay, I got the original problem fixed by doing what you suggested, but what if I added a link in `.lb-caption` that you had to click? I edited the lightbox script ([click here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jK1PfQQC)) and added `this.$lightbox.find('.lb-caption a').on('click', function() { alert("Clicked link."); });`, but for someone reason that's not working (it works with just `.lb-caption` though). [Here's the new codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjAtz).

Comment: I think the `a` probably doesn't exist when you bind that handler. You might try `this.$lightbox.find('.lb-caption').on('click', 'a', function() { alert("Clicked link."); });`. Changing the library code will make it more difficult to upgrade if you need to though...

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not too sure how it works, but it works :)

I added a function

```
  this.$lightbox.find('.lb-caption').on('click', function() {
    alert("CLICKED.");
    return false;
  });
```

and this function.

```
  this.$overlay.hide().on('click', function() {
    //_this.end();
    alert("...");
    return false;
  });
```

maybe will adjust any other function, which is not so much needed.

[see here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrnCl)

Answer (score -1):

There was a comma missing after `".lb-caption"`, and as **Jason P** said this will also not worked, you have to directly bind to element.

```
$(".lb-caption").on("click",function(){
  alert("CLICKED.");
});
```

see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/axnhr)